# Simple HashTable implementation using an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I'm having a problem with implementing a very simple HashTable using an array. The problem is that the first Item put in the `HashTable` is always `AVAILABLE`. Maybe you guys can see what is going wrong. This is the `HashTable` class:

```
public class HashTable {

    private Item[] data;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private static final Item AVAILABLE = new Item("Available", null);

    public HashTable(int capacity) {

        this.capacity = capacity; 
        data = new Item[capacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            data[i] = AVAILABLE;
        }
        size = 0;
    }

    public int size() {

        return size;
    }

    public int hashThis(String key) {

        return key.hashCode() % capacity; 
    }

    public Object get(String key) {

        int hash = hashThis(key);

        while(data[hash] != AVAILABLE && data[hash].key() != key) {

            hash = (hash + 1) % capacity;
        }
        return data[hash].element();
    }

    public void put(String key, Object element) {

        if(key != null) {
            size++;
            int hash = hashThis(key);
            while(data[hash] != AVAILABLE && data[hash].key() != key) {

                hash = (hash + 1) % capacity;
            }

            data[hash] = new Item(key, element);

        }

    }

    public Object remove(String key) {
        // not important now.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't remove");
    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = "<HashTable[";
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {

            s += data[i].toString();
            if(i < this.size() - 1) {

                s += ",";
            }
        }
        s += "]>";
        return s;
    }

}
```

For more clarity, this is the `Item` class:

```
public class Item {

    private String key;
    private Object element;

    public Item(String key, Object element) {

        this.setKey(key);
        this.setElement(element);
    }

    public String key() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Object element() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(Object element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = "<Item(";
        s += this.key() + "," + this.element() + ")>";
        return s;
    }

}
```

To give an example:

```
HashTable ht = new HashTable(10);
ht.put("1", "a");
```

The output of toString() after putting has to be:

```
"<HashTable[<Item(1,a)>]>"
```

but I get:

```
"<HashTable[<Item(Available,null)>]>"
```

**update:** I should probably mention that the next Item gets put correctly and the one after that is not again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `toString` method. You loop for 0 - size when size = 1 so once so you only print out the first value in your hashTable problem is the first value in your hash table is not a real value it's an AVAILABLE you have to do something like this

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to move the index over.

```
public String toString() {
   String s = "<HashTable[";
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   while(count < this.size()) {

        //Skip the AVAILABLE cells
        if(data[i] == AVAILABLE) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        s += data[i].toString();
        if(count < this.size() - 1) {
            s += ",";
        }
        count++;
    }
    s += "]>";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: @Loolooii the loop in the `toString` method? Every time you have a cell that is not `AVAILABLE` `i` gets incremented so it should stop when `i=size`. So if `size` is set correctly (which it appears to be) and there is an element in the array that doesn't equal `AVAILABLE` it should stop.

Comment: Yes the loop in the toString method. I know, it should stop, but somehow it does not?!

Comment: And the loop in put() also doesn't stop when I change && to || .

Comment: @Loolooii I wasn't sure about the `put` method so I removed it. I'll edit the loop so it will stop in the `toString` method (but it should work as is)

Comment: Yes, I just tried debugging and: it goes in the first if and after continue it goes back to while-condition and keeps doing this. So data[i] is always AVAILABLE.

Comment: @Loolooii I know why that's my bad. I'll fix it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9539/discussion-between-loolooii-and-twain249)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for toString() if still interested in the solution, I ran it and its fine:

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "<HashTable[";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.capacity; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].Element != null)
        {
            s += data[i].toString();
            if (i < this.size - 1)
            {
                s += ",";
            }
         }
     }
     s += "]>";
     return s;
}
```